# How to disable Google Maps realign north button

Tags: android, google-maps, user-interface

Hi I would like to know how to disable the north align compass button in the top left corner of Google Maps. I linked an image to show what I am talking about. I have found out how to disable other UI components but I find nothing about disabling this button. I am using android studio.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `UiSettings` object of maps has a `setCompassEnabled()` method that you can use to enable or disable the realign north button.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings

The simple activity that shows how to do it

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TO Hide compass Just add this line where you are loading google map

```
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
```